# Azure Automation Managment not able to execute run book

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I am using Azure Automation Management 2.0.1. I am not able find Start method for Runbooks to execute a runbook. How do this with 2.0.1

```
var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation.AutomationManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert));
var ct = new CancellationToken();

var content = await client.Runbooks.ListByNameAsync("MyAutomationAccountName", "MyRunbookName", ct);

var firstOrDefault = content?.Runbooks.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstOrDefault != null)
{
    var operation = client.Runbooks.Start("MyAutomationAccountName", new RunbookStartParameters(firstOrDefault.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [automationManagementClient.Jobs.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt459726.aspx)

```
public static JobCreateResponse Create(
    this IJobOperations operations,
    string resourceGroupName,
    string automationAccount,
    JobCreateParameters parameters
)
```

You can find a full sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt465763.aspx) this would be the relevant part -

```
private void JobStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        // Check for runbook name
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RunbookName.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PublishState.Text)) throw new ArgumentNullException(RunbookName.Text);

        // Create job create parameters
        var jcparam = new JobCreateParameters
        {
            Properties = new JobCreateProperties
            {
                Runbook = new RunbookAssociationProperty
                {
                    // associate the runbook name
                    Name = RunbookName.Text
                },

                // pass parameters to runbook if any
                Parameters = null
            }
        };

        // create runbook job. This gives back JobId
        var job = automationManagementClient.Jobs.Create(this.automationAccountName, jcparam).Job;

        JobGuid.Text = JobId.Text = job.Properties.JobId.ToString();

        Log.Text += (String.Format("\nJob Started for Runbook {0} , JobId {1}", RunbookName.Text, JobId.Text));
}
```